# iOS - Convert part of an Array Element into a String

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, xmlnode

So I loosely followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) for parsing HTML into a Master/Detail App.

I am trying to change the NSArray to a NSString, but the only array element (there is only one element) seems to not be fully parsed.

My Code:

viewcontroller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface viciViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextView *label;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
    IBOutlet UITextView *translation;
    IBOutlet UIButton *transButton;
    BOOL connectedToInternet;
}

-(IBAction)translateButton;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "viciViewController.h"
#import "TFHpple.h"

@interface viciViewController ()

@end

@implementation viciViewController

- (BOOL)connectedToInternet
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: NULL];

    return ([response statusCode]==200)?YES:NO;
}

-(IBAction)translateButton {
    if ([self connectedToInternet] == NO)
    {
        translation.text = @"Sorry, you need an internet connection to translate.";
        // Not connected to the internet
    }
    else
    {
        // Connected to the internet

    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *toTranslate = self->textfield.text;
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=%@", toTranslate];
    NSURL *translationUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:(url)];
    NSData *translationHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:translationUrl];


    TFHpple *translationParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:translationHtmlData];

    // 3
    NSString *translationXpathQueryString = @"/html/body/pre";
    NSArray *translationOutput = [translationParser searchWithXPathQuery:translationXpathQueryString];

    NSString * result = [[translationOutput valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"Response %@", result);
}
```

The log in the console says:

```
Response {
    nodeChildArray =     (
                {
            nodeContent = "\nsemper               ADV    POS                         \nsemper  ADV   [XXXAX]  \nalways;\n\n";
            nodeName = text;
        }
    );
    nodeName = pre;
    raw = "<pre>\nsemper               ADV    POS                         \nsemper  ADV   [XXXAX]  \nalways;\n\n</pre>";
}
```

So, question: is it possible to get *just* nodeContent as a NSString and turn the `\n` into carriage returns?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Dump the array to the console - print it out - and then figure out how to format what I assume are an array of strings. You can create a NSMutableString and then keep loading it, when done add that to the TextView and your done.

Comment: @DavidH It is just one element, and also what???

Comment: Did you see this line: NSArray *translationOutput = ... ? Ah, you mean  the array has one element - so print it out and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TFHppleElement` does exactly that:

Replace the following lines in **your** code

```
NSString * result = [[translationOutput valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"Response %@", result);
```

with the following:

```
NSString *translatedString = ((TFHppleElement *)translationOutput[0]).firstChild.content;
NSLog(@"%@", translatedString);
```

***Don't forget to include `TFHppleElement.h`***

---

**Output**

If you send `semper` the parsed result stored in `translatedString` is

> semper               ADV    POS
>   semper  ADV   [XXXAX]
>   always;

Comment: I tried this, and the console is outputting `(null)`. Any ideas?

Comment: It's working on my machine ;). I think you are not sending the right url. Could you please `NSLog()` your `NSString` `url`? and see if it's like `http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=semper`?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please do the same on your machine. The method is placed in your AppDelegate. Do you now get the results?

Comment: btw: you should start using properties and accessing values such as `self->textfield.text` through its getters and setters ;)

Comment: But how would you set the value of `toTranslate` as the text in the textfield?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32177/discussion-between-has-and-zuludeltaniner)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dictionary, ask it for the nodeChildArray object, ask that array for its first object, ask that dictionary for its node content. Now you have a string. Use the NSString method that breaks up a string given a sub string (@"\n", two backslashes), now you get an array of strings. Iterate through all, again using the string method to remove leading and trailing white space. If the string has length you can again get an array of strings separated by white space or use NSScanner to do it.